# Storing Settings for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

This is a very general and noob question, but I am a noob with real programming so...

How can I set a Boolean setting and store that setting so that when you exit the app and come back the setting is how the user left it? I also need to know how to read that setting and enable features based on them.

I plan to have two settings in my app, one for location and one for turning off an alert on attempting to exit the app (I know this is considered bad by most people, but trust me, it makes sense for this app).

I have no idea how to do this, things like this and cookies have always confounded me, so a good explanation would be greatly appreciated.

My app is in C# and XAML if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might want to take a look at this article: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings

And this other SO question: [When should I save settings on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243864/when-should-i-save-settings-on-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
// save value
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyName"] = true;
// read value
var val = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("MyName")
    ? (bool) IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyName"]
    : false; // false is default value
```

Answer (score 0):

I like MSDN binding-based example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx

(Thanks to Dmitry T. for the link on SO.)