# Windows phone 7 Database adding values

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7

I am now creating an app, that allows user to create and retrieve data from local database. There is one column named LIKE with a default value of int 0. I have a button, but is there anyway that I can press that button then the default value of int 0 will become 1 ? Everytime I press it will add one to the default value int. How can I do that ?

Comment: I recommend you go through this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Eugene This is not what I needed, I need a auto adding of value int 1 to the LIKE column.

Comment: You need to retrieve whatever class you use to store your value, increment it by 1, and then submit changes back to database.

Comment: hoping for some examples that I can refer to =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your database context is set as in the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) I mentioned in the comment, your button click event can look like the following:

```
    private void IncrementLikes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //where Likes is your ObservableCollection keeping data from database
        LikeItem oneAndOnly = Likes.First() as LikeItem;
        //you pulled one and only LikeItem object, now you increment the likes count
        oneAndOnly.LikesCount += 1;
        //and here you tell the database that the changes need to be saved.
        //This call can be delayed to the OnNavigatedFrom event,
        //  depending on your needs.
        LikeDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

and here is some supporting code that belongs to the .cs file of the page:

```
    //your database context
    private YourDatabaseDataContext LikeDB;

    // Define an observable collection property that controls can bind to.
    private ObservableCollection<LikeItem> _likes;
    public ObservableCollection<LikeItem> Likes
    {
        get
        {
            return _likes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_likes != value)
            {
                _likes = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Likes");
            }
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LikeDB = new YourDatabaseDataContext(YourDatabaseDataContext.DBConnectionString);
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Define the query to gather all of the to-do items.
        var likesFromDB = from LikeItem like in LikeDB.Likes
                            select like;

        // Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
        Likes = new ObservableCollection<LikeItem>(likesFromDB);

        // Call the base method.
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Using the database for just one value may be too much, so you might want to look at other alternatives, such as Windows Phone [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088670/storing-settings-for-windows-phone).